# Vue.js two way binding using a custom type

Tags: vue.js

I thought that two way data flow was not just discouraged but impossible between parent and child components in Vue.js.  However I've discovered it's actually possible using a custom class as a prop.

**Custom class:**

```
    class MyClass {
      constructor(val) {
        this.val = val;
      }
    }
```

**Parent template:**

```
 <div>
  <child :obj="obj"></child>
</div>
```

**Child props:**

```
props: {
  obj: MyClass
}
```

**Child template:**

```
<div>
  <button @click='obj.val="changed"'>Change val</button>
</div>
```

Here is a working example: https://codepen.io/francoisgaudin/pen/XWdBOxN

So now I'm wondering why this is possible - is it deliberately allowed or is it a loophole that should not be exploited??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in Vue.js documentation on the "one way data flow" (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow).  They specify the following caveat:

> Note that objects and arrays in JavaScript are passed by reference, so
> if the prop is an array or object, mutating the object or array itself
> inside the child component will affect parent state.

So one way data flow is not strictly enforced and there is no error or warning in this case.  This is a loophole - (which is best avoided).

Answer (score 0):

You're able to modify the object because object references are values in Javascript - which makes objects act like they are passed by reference.

In other words:

Javascript always passes by value, but for arrays and objects the value is a reference to the object.

https://medium.com/nodesimplified/javascript-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference-in-javascript-fcf10305aa9c

It's allowed because the alternative is copying the whole object (which could include nested objects and is not really practical).

Also, this is an opinion, but you should not do this.

Comment: This is a good explanation of Javascript's handling of objects, but it doesn't completely answer the question since it doesn't mention how this fits in with Vue's supposed one-way data flow.

Answer (score -1):

you can use Vue's `$emit` feature to communicate between child/parent, more examples here :

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html

Comment: Yes - that's the recommended pattern.  But my question refers to what seems to be a loophole that allows child components to modify the state of parent components. Clearly the loophole should not be exploited, but maybe it should be mentioned in the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

I do not see a downside of using it, more than loosing the track where the object is modified in a very nested child components. I will play around a bit more with your codepen, I also wanna know why it is possible, and `Avoid mutating a prop directly` error is not raised.